# How to load React-Native Bundle File in React-Native Component

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, dynamic-linking

- I am having a requirement where i have a Primary App and a Secondary
  App.
- created a bundle of Secondary App and added in Primary App's
  certain folder.
- Now I want to load that bundle in Primary App's certain component and run it.

Please suggest how can i proceed with the same requirement.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I too have the same requirement. Please Guide and any help would be appreciated.